# How to make a JDBC connection to MS SQL Server on Azure via Azure Active Directory User

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-active-directory

I have a J2EE web application. Database connection is made via JDBC. Now the web application needs to be deployed on Azure cloud. The JDBC Connection needs to be made to MS SQL Server . Authentication to database is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'

I found the java libraries. It seems the code is looking for older library: adal4j-1.6.6.jar instead of the newer version: msal4j-1.7.1.jar

With msal4j-1.7.1 loaded I still get the error message: Failed to load ADAL4J Java library.

With the older library I get a different message & log entry :

With the older library I get a different message & log entry:
10-20@16:19:22293041 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9]      labware.web.admin.DataSourceBean     - Error saving data source in method saveDS.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/AuthorizationGrant 
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.adalContextExists(SQLServerConnection.java:4546) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4438) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4415) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4380) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:289) 
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:125)
```

I am adding the missing jars. But it seems there should be better way of doing this . Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the connection string?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://<domain_name>:1433;database=MyDatabase;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword

addition to this username and password is passed.

One more point to update here is that the code is traditional JDBC API code

Answer (score 1):

Was easy problem to fix by using maven. Microsoft Azure jdbc drivers does not come with run time dependency jars it needs. Easy fix is to use maven. The pom.xml should have the following dependencies. As guessed, Maven does all the hard work downloads all the dependency jars.

Following dependency enteries are needed in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

adal4j is needed, the azure gives us the capacity to log into sql server using a federated or active directory user via oauth 2.0.